# How to set axis label color using chartkick.js in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, chartkick

If I have a column chart component in a react component like so:

```
import React from "react";
import {ColumnChart} from "react-chartkick";

export function BarChart({data, title, xlabel, ylabel}) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.dataVisualisation}>
      <div className={classes.title} >{title}</div>
      <ColumnChart
        data={data}
        xtitle={xlabel}
        ytitle={ylabel}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can I specify the color of the text for the labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building off of Keikai's answer I got it to work.

The property that sets the color of the labels is:

library > scales > yAxes/xAxes > scaleLabel > fontColor

```
import Chartkick, { LineChart } from "react-chartkick";
import "chart.js";

<LineChart
  data={{ "2017-01-01": 11, "2017-01-02": 6, "2017-01-03": 20 }}
  library={{
    legend: {
      labels: {
        fontColor: "blue"
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          scaleLabel: { fontColor: "blue" }, // this line sets the label's font to blue
          ticks: { fontColor: "blue" },
          gridLines: { drawBorder: true, color: "blue" }
        }
      ]
    }
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's kind of deep.

We can find those stuff inside the document of **chartkick**

---

library > legend > labels > fontColor

library > scales > yAxes/xAxes > gridLines (?) > color

```
import Chartkick, { LineChart } from "react-chartkick";
import "chart.js";

<LineChart
  data={{ "2017-01-01": 11, "2017-01-02": 6, "2017-01-03": 20 }}
  library={{
    legend: {
      labels: {
        fontColor: "blue"
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          ticks: { fontColor: "blue" },
          gridLines: { drawBorder: true, color: "blue" }
        }
      ]
    }
  }}
/>
```

[image]

Comment: This works for coloring the ticks but how do I set the label color as well? e.g. if I had the label 'dates' for the x axis, how would I set that to be green.

Comment: Yeah, it changes the color of the axis ticks and the grid lines, as it does in your image, but the color of the label remains unchanged.

Comment: They still remain the same color for me